# An oddly formed sequence?

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence, no-computers, formation-of-numbers, number-property

I've been playing around with sequences lately and came across one that was rather, *odd*.

> $101$, $123$, $147$, $189$, $191$, $213$, $217$, $279$, $...$

###### Hints

Let $N_i = 101$...

> $N_{i - 4}$ through $N_{i - 1}$ is $11$, $33$, $77$, $99$.
>  $N_{i - 8}$ through $N_{i - 5}$ is $1$, $3$, $7$, $9$.

---

Can you determine the next number in my sequence?

Answer (score 1):

Not an extremely elegant solution, but

> the complete sequence
>  $$11, 33, 77, 99, 101, 123, 147, 189, 191, 213, 217, 279, ...$$
>  is made up of four interleaved arithmetic progressions, where three of them have an increment equal to $90$, and the other one (the third one, starting with $77$) has an increment equal to $70$. The subsequences are:
>  $11, 101, 191,...$ (increment $90$)
>  $33, 123, 213,...$ (increment $90$)
>  $77, 147, 217,...$ (increment $70$)
>  $99, 189, 279,...$ (increment $90$).

The next term is

> the continuation of the subsequence $11, 101, 191,...$, which is $281$.

Comment: Not quite, though I love this answer  +1 from me! I’ll add another hint in case you’d like to see why this answer doesn’t fit.

Comment: I will say that the answer itself is correct, but the *why* is wrong.